# Display immediately data from csv file to handsontable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, csv

I want to display data from a *.csv file in an array on my web page. So, when the user click on the button, I want my data to appear in my array immediately.

This is how I get the data from the *.csv :

```
<?php 
        $file=file('Classeur1.csv');


        foreach ($file as $ligne)
        {
            list($index,$id_essai,$nom_local,$nombre_traitement,$nombre_blocs,$type_rotations,$essai_ou_suivi,$thematique,$annee_debut,$annee_fin)=explode(";",$ligne );

        }

    ?>
```

Now, when I click on the button, I call a javascript function like this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#insert_data_csv').click(function(){

        $.post("import_data_csv.php",{array_data:list_data , array_handsontable:data_essai});

    });

});
```

In my post method, I send the arrays : one from the csv and one from the handsontable.

This is how I declare my list_data :

```
var index_essai = "<?php echo $index ;?>";
    id_essai = "<?php echo $id_essai;?>";
    nom_local_essai = "<?php echo $nom_local;?>";
    nombre_traitements = "<?php echo $nombre_traitement;?>";
    nombre_blocs = "<?php echo $nombre_blocs;?>";
    type_rotation =" <?php echo $type_rotations;?>";
    essais_ou_suivis =" <?php echo $essai_ou_suivi;?>";
    thematique = "<?php echo $thematique;?>";
    annee_debut = "<?php  echo $annee_debut;?>";
    annee_fin = <?php echo $annee_fin;?>;

list_data = [index_essai,
            id_essai,
            nom_local_essai,
            nombre_traitements,
            nombre_blocs,
            type_rotation,
            essais_ou_suivis,
            thematique,
            annee_debut,
            annee_fin
            ];
```

Eventually, my ajax code :

```
<?php
$array_data = $_POST['array_data'];
$array_handsontable = $_POST['array_handsontable'];
$i = 0;

foreach ($array_data as $ligne)
{
    $array_handsontable[$i][1] = $ligne;
    $i = $i+1;
    echo $ligne;
}
?>
```

I know that my data are well send because I can display them in the console from the ajax file. But they don't display in my handsontable immediatly. 
Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Insteed of Using explode use below code for exploding record and putting in array.

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("Classeur1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you but how can I instantly display that data in my page ?